# PreferenceCategory - line breaks or ellipsizing

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my PreferenceCategory the textview does not change its height when the text becomes too long. It just breaks the line and looks weird, as the size is not changed... I have also tried ellipsizing, but without success... 
is there a way to get a preferencecategory-view to change its size or if not to ellipsize its content?

Answer (score 3):

I just found it out myself how to get this TextView to ellipsize its content. 
Here's my solution:

Create a Custom PreferenceCategory and override `onBindView(View view)`, the `view`-objects holds your TextView that you can get to ellipsize then...

```
public class CustomPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    if(view instanceof TextView){
        TextView tv = (TextView)view;
        tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        tv.setLines(1);
        tv.setSingleLine();
    }
}
```

}

and reference it in your xml-preference layout like that:

```
<com.package.name.CustomPreferenceCategory android:key="KEY_ABC" />
```

thats all :-)